# Grails - how hasMany maintains the order inside Set/PersistentSet?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

When you use `hasMany` `books` it is defined as `Set` or [PersistentSet](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/collection/PersistentSet.html) if it is get as proxy.

In the [Grails docs](http://docs.grails.org/2.5.x/guide/GORM.html#defaultSortOrder) says:

> you can configure sorting at the association level.

The above means that all collections of Book instances will by default be sorted by the book title:

```
class Author {
  String name
  static hasMany = [books: Book]

  static mapping = {
      books sort: "title"
  }
}

class Book  {
  String title
  static belongsTo = [author: Author]
}
```

In my tests, when you get books of an author always come sorted, however I do not understand how you can keep them sorted if they are saved in a Set or PersistentSet (The underlying collection is a HashSet)

Why when I get any author the books always gets sorted by title if the query results are put inside a Set/PersistentSet?

How Grails do it?

Comment: What's your exact question?

Comment: I had edited the post